# How to update Listview from background service

Tags: android

I have Background service for downloading the image from server.I want update my UI or ListView when download is finished.Want to change that text on button to "downloaded". Please help me out
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show, what you have done till now.

Comment: please put your code what you have done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you can through a broadcast from background service which will get received by your main thread say activity. Then from `onRecieve()` method you can update your `ListView` by updating your model and calling `notifyDatasetChanged()` of your adapter.

Example of Broadcast Reciever
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_broadcast_receivers.htm

Or you can pass the handler of main thread to the service usnig intent and can update the main thread or your `listview` by posting message on main thread using that handler.

Example of Handler
https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

Comment: can you have any link or code regarding the update UI using handler

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score -1):

You can't update views from background thread!
After you finish to download the image you need to call:
You can read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html).

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // refresh list 
    }
});
```